# How to get selected value from select tag using javascript and go to another page using that value

Tags: javascript, html, select, hyperlink

I have a  select tag where it contains some values, as shown below:

```
         <select id="menu" SIZE=6 onChange="go()">
          <option value="">Select city</option>
    <option value="delhi" >delhi</option>  
    <option value="kolkata" >kolkata</option>  
    <option value="mumbai" >mumbai</option>
           </select>
```

Now i am using below script for this, where it get the selected value from the drop down,

```
      <script>
        function go(){

var sel = document.getElementById('menu');
       var sv = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

              //  here i  need to make a specific link using this selected drop down value


          }

          </script>
```

I just need to know how can i make use of this selected value and go to specific link like

```
       window.location.href='getCityDetails.jsp?c=sv'; // this is not working properly
```

Can anyone suggest me best solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script>
    function go(){

   var sel = document.getElementById('menu');
   var sv = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location.href='getCityDetails.jsp?c=' + sv;

      }

      </script>
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

HTML :

```
<select id="menu" SIZE=6 onChange="go(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select city</option>
    <option value="delhi" >delhi</option>  
    <option value="kolkata" >kolkata</option>  
    <option value="mumbai" >mumbai</option>
</select>
```

Javascript :

```
function go(desination){
    if (destination != ''){
         window.location.href='getCityDetails.jsp?c=' + desination;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to concatenate the string properly. try this:

```
window.location.href='getCityDetails.jsp?c=' + sv;
```

Answer (score 0):

-- You can use--

```
var TaskType = document.form1.SelTaskType.value;
```

--  TaskType will display selected option from below

```
<select id="SelTaskType" name="SelTaskType" >
<option selected>-- select --</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
</select>
```